# Back to PHP from jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to echo the HTML dropdown value through jQuery:

```
<select id="single">
  <option>Single</option>
  <option>Single2</option>
</select>

<script>
  function displayVals() {
    var singleValues = $( "#single" ).val();
    $( "p" ).html( "<b>Single:</b> " + singleValues);
  }
  $( "select" ).change( displayVals );
  displayVals();
</script>
```

and echo the dropdown value in PHP:

```
<?php
    echo $single;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access select values in PHP without first submitting the form.

Here's a sample form which submits to a file called submit.php

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">

<select id="my_select" name="my_select">
    <option value="1">One</select>
    <option value="2">Two</select>
    <option value="3">Three</select>
</select>

</form>
```

The contents of submit.php would look like this...

```
<?php
echo $_POST['my_select']; // Will output the value of my_select when the form was submitted
?>
```

You could also use ajax to submit data from your form to a PHP page, have the PHP page generate some HTML output and return it back to your jQuery, from there you can insert the resulting HTML into an element (div) in your page.

```
<form id="my_form" method="post" action="submit.php">

<label>Select the number of items you'd like @ £5.00 each</label><br>
<select name="my_select">
    <option value="1">One</select>
    <option value="2">Two</select>
    <option value="3">Three</select>
</select>

</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Create a PHP page to receive the data from the form.

```
$price = 5.00;
$noOfItems = $_POST['my_select'];

$totalCost = $price * $noOfItems;

echo "<p>$noOfItems @ $price will cost you $totalCost";
```

Then use some jQuery to submit the data from your form to the PHP back in the background, and then put the resulting HTML into the #result div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document.ready(function(){

    $("#my_select").change(function(){
        $.post("submit.php", $("#my_form").serialize(), function(response){
            $("#result").html(response);
        });
    });

}))
</script>
```

Comment: What I need is use and instant publish the value of select list in sum of couple of numbers/values. Ex. in dropdown is 2 types delivery costs and I want to publish the product value including shipment instant after selection was made.

Comment: ok, maybe what you need to do is submit the form to a PHP file using ajax. Have the PHP file generate your HTML markup and return it, then you can output the response inside a DIV or other element. Let me put together a quick sample.

Comment: I've added some further information above. You can also perform your calculations using Javascript too. You don't need to use PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your help.